# datepicker not working with jQuery dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have datattable of user data, and each row contain edit button to open edit form. I'm open it using jQuery dialog box and submit for using ajax submit, but when loading form datepickers it is not working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could it be that it's appearing behind something? You could try changing its z-index to move it forward.

Comment: @amadan no i checked

Answer (score 0):

You are inverting `name` and `id` attributes.

When you use:

```
$("#activation_on").datepicker(...
```

jQuery selects the element with id= `activation_on` because `#` is the id selector. But your element's id is `id="activation_on1"`.
The same happens on your `valid_to` field.
You can change their ids or change the jquery to:

```
$("#activation_on1").datepicker(...
```

and

```
$("#valid_to1").datepicker(...
```

Take a look at a working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dudu84/42yoLLgg/2/

Comment: adjusted, but still same

Comment: Can you please post the portion of code where you are importing jquery in  "edit.php"?

Comment: I'm not using any jquery in edit.php. user.js file contain those js codes.

Comment: Yes. I see that. But where are you importing jquery libraries for user.js? Please, take a look at the fiddle (just added it in the answer) and see if it helps.

Comment: still not :( user.js have another fucntion for add user form, but there its working.. don't know why its not working for edit-user.

Comment: If you open the console in the browser, does it show any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128972/discussion-between-dil-and-luiz-eduardo-de-christo).